# Number of optima of product of convex functions

Tags: convex-optimization, products

I am dealing with a function, which is a product of two strongly convex functions, and trying to determine the number of its local minimum. 
For example, I have $$H=f(x)\cdot g(x)$$, in which both $f$ and $g$ are strongly convex functions and thus both have only one minimum themselves.

I wonder if there is any theory or conclusion about the number of its local minima. 
Intuitively, I suspect it to be 2. (I know in general $H$ is not convex.)

Thanks!

Comment: Suppose $f(x)=e^x$ and $g(x)=e^{-x}$, so that $h(x)=1$. Now consider replacing $f(x)$ with $(1+\epsilon\sin x)e^x$...

Comment: Comment aside: `optima` is already a plural in Latin. No `s` required.

Comment: @Rahul Wow, excellent example. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Bernard Got that, thanks!

Comment: You might want to consider posting and accosting answer yourself if you figured it out

Comment: @Rahul What if $f$ and $g$ are both quadratic functions? Actually the variable $x$ in my problem is matrix and both two functions are quadratic.

Comment: Consider these three possibilities: $$f(x) = x^2 \qquad g(x) = x^2$$ $$f(x) = (x-1)^2 \quad g(x)=(x+1)^2$$ $$f(x)=(x-1)^2+1 \qquad g(x)=(x+1)^2-1$$

Comment: For multivariable functions you can more than two local minima, for example when $f(x,y)=10x^2+(y-1)^2$ and $g(x,y)=(x-1)^2+10y^2$ then $f(x,y)g(x,y)$ has minima near $(0,1)$, $(1,0)$, and $(0,0)$. Probably lots of local minima are possible if $f$ and $g$ can be less than zero.

Comment: @MichaelGrant So for these cases there are at most two local minima, right ?

Comment: @Rahul Yeah, you are right. Thanks! Actually I am dealing with a function $f=trace( RR^H WW^H-RW+RR^H )$, where $R$ and $W$ are matrices and the superscript means hermitian transpose. Do you have any idea about its number of local minima?

Comment: Sorry to resurrect an old question, but what is the answer? And does it hold also if the functions are *strictly* (but not *strongly*) convex? Could anyone please provide a reference?Thank you.